# Install remote desktop session host remotely

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, azure, remote-desktop-services

I've removed the remote desktop host role from one of my Azue VM, so I can't RDP into it.
I have tried to recreate the endpoints and even the VM with no luck.
I can't either access remotely with Server Manager; getting this error: **The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the services on the destination is running"**

I cannot connect remotely to the registry **Make sure this computer is on the network, has remote administration enabled, and that both computers are running the remote registry service**

PsPing tells me **The remote computer refuses the network connection**

Which workaround can I follow to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, at the end, as I needed some files from that VM, what I did is download the .vhd of that VM (it was in the Azure storage) and attach it as a new disk (thourg disk manager), so I was able to browse it.

After that, with the disk mounted, I could access the registry (regedit -> Load Hive) and enable back the RDP to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Your remote connectivity issue(s) aren't unprecedented, a TechNet Article advising resizing the VM from the managers console forces a refresh to default network settings.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/cb4a06b8-7aa3-45e4-aca8-0d3cbc69eb4b/unable-to-connect-to-azure-vm-using-rdp-connection?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Remotely reinstalling RDP Server has various methods, you're already comfortable with those ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I already tried resize and recreate the VM with no luck.